# doxygen problem running ghost script unrecoverable error

Tags: doxygen

I get the following error with doxygen 1.9.5:

```
Error: /configurationerror in --setpagedevice--
Additional information: [/PageSize [0 0]]
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   (%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0)   --dict:1/2(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   (%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0)   1   0   0   false   --dict:1/1(L)--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   0Policy   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   0Policy   0Policy   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1988   1   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   0Policy   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %ztokenexec_continue   (scanner state)   0Policy   0Policy   0Policy   0Policy   1986   8   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1984   11   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1938   10   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1937   16   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   --dict:1/10(L)--   0Policy   3   %dict_continue   1934   19   3   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:776/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:79/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 127
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
error: Problems running gs. Check your installation!
Error: /configurationerror in --setpagedevice--
Additional information: [/PageSize [0 0]]
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   (%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0)   --dict:1/2(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   (%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0)   1   0   0   false   --dict:1/1(L)--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   0Policy   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   0Policy   0Policy   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1988   1   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   0Policy   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %ztokenexec_continue   (scanner state)   0Policy   0Policy   0Policy   0Policy   1986   8   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1984   11   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1938   10   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1937   16   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   --dict:1/10(L)--   0Policy   3   %dict_continue   1934   19   3   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:776/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:79/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 127
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
error: Problems running gs. Check your installation!
```

I do not think ghostscript is the problem because I am able to create the docu for a simple MWE.

Is there a log file that points me to the problem? For instance, when I have latex macro file containing some latex errors, there is a file `_formulas.log`.

Is there something similar here?

UPDATE:

As mentioned in the comments, I use cmake as build system and the relevant snippet in the `CMakeLists.txt` reads

```
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  SET( DOXYGEN_IN           ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/doc-config.dox   )
  SET( DOXYGEN_OUT          ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/options.dox           )

  add_custom_target (doc ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory docs
                     COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT} 
                     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
                     COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM
                     )
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

So to add the option `-d extcmd`, I modified it to

```
add_custom_target (doc ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory docs
                         COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT} -d extcmd
                         WORKING_DIRECTORY)
```

but that seems to have no effect and generates the same output shown above.

UPDATE 2:

As mentioned in the command, the `-d extcmd` must be placed like this

```
add_custom_target (doc ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory docs
                         COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} -d extcmd ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
                         WORKING_DIRECTORY)
```

This brings me actually closer to the real problem. There is a whole bunch of statements of the form

```
Executing external command `dvips -q -D 600 -n 1 -p 94 -o _form93_dark_tmp.ps _formulas_dark.dvi`
Executing external command `gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -P- -dNOSAFER -sDEVICE=eps2write -o _form93_dark_tmp.eps -f _form93_dark_tmp.ps`
Executing external command `gs -q -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pnggray -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r252 -sOutputFile=form_93_dark.png _form93_dark_tmp_corr.eps`
Executing external command `dvips -q -D 600 -n 1 -p 95 -o _form94_dark_tmp.ps _formulas_dark.dvi`
Executing external command `gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -P- -dNOSAFER -sDEVICE=eps2write -o _form94_dark_tmp.eps -f _form94_dark_tmp.ps`
Executing external command `gs -q -dNOSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pnggray -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r252 -sOutputFile=form_94_dark.png _form94_dark_tmp_corr.eps`
Error: /configurationerror in --setpagedevice--
Additional information: [/PageSize [0 0]]
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   (%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0)   --dict:1/2(ro)(G)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   (%%BoundingBox: 0 0 0 0)   1   0   0   false   --dict:1/1(L)--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   0Policy   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   0Policy   0Policy   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   1   3   %oparray_pop   1989   1   3   %oparray_pop   1988   1   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1977   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   0Policy   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   %ztokenexec_continue   (scanner state)   0Policy   0Policy   0Policy   0Policy   1986   8   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1984   11   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1938   10   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   1937   16   3   %oparray_pop   0Policy   --dict:1/10(L)--   0Policy   3   %dict_continue   1934   19   3   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:776/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:79/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 127
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
error: Problems running gs. Check your installation!
[100%] Built target doc
```

As you can see, the first 93 forms work fine but in the 94th form, there seems to be problem with the underlying formulae. Checking out the build folder, the file `_form94_dark_tmp_corr.eps` is a full black picture.

UPDATE 3:

I was able to figure out the exact issue by inspecting the `formula.repository` file. The issue is the form 100

```
\_form#99=14x14:$ \sparseMatrix $
\_form#100=0x0:$ \rightSideVector $
```

Here, `\newcommand{\rightSideVector}{\mathbb{b}}` is a very simple command and being used in a function documentation  `* the @p rhsVector \f$ \rightSideVector \f$, and`

Interestingly, `\newcommand{\sparseMatrix}{\mathbb{A}}` is defined in the same fashion but worked fine (form 99).

Any ideas what might be the problem?

UPDATE 4:

As stated in the comments, there is an issue with lower case letters in \mathbb. Here is an example demonstrating the problem:

```
# file mwe.cc

/**
* Example function
* @param a: \f$ \myVec \f$
*/
void foo(double a)

int main()
{
return 0;
}

# file macros.tex
\newcommand{\myVec}{\mathbb{b}}

#file doc-config.dox
FORMULA_MACROFILE      = ./macros.tex
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = amsmath amsfonts
INPUT                  = ./mwe.cc
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens with the current doxygen version (1.9.8)? Which command are you giving? Maybe  invoking doxygen with `-d extcmd` gives some pointers. Is the log you show the complete log?

Comment: @albert I can only use 1.9.5.  I use the command make doc since I use cmake with docygen. I showed you the entire output of the command make doc. Any hints?

Comment: Only hints at the moment use `-d extcmd` and update (although the later doesn't seem possible). Regarding the `make doc` I assume this is a `Makefile` for your own project. you probably need to hack a bit around there or use `make VERBOSE=1 doc` or `make -n doc` to see which commands are being executed by `make`

Comment: Do you know how I can add the -d extcmd option to cmake/make?

Comment: Edit the Makefile / CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Do you know what cmake variable is relevant for adding options like -d extcmd?

Comment: No as I don't know how you call doxygen in cmake. just search for doxygen in the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Running make VERBOSE=1 doc or make -n doc does not bring more information. I added my question by adding a snippet of my CMakeLists.txt. Can you help as for adding the option -d extcmd?

Comment: The `-d extcmd` must be before the reference to the doxyfile

Comment: Yes, that helped. I updated my question again. I think there is a problem with a latex equation. Do you know how to narrow down the problem further by, e.g., finding out the source file in which this equation/form is located?

Comment: Have a go with the option `-d formula` this will leave the resuting formulas / intermediate files in the HTML directory so you cans see if you can find the formula 93 and look in the `_fomula.tex` for formula 93 and check from that place. An alternative might be to use the MathJax rendering (`USE_MATHJAX=YES`) as at that moment the you will get a ryellow box with red letters with an error message on the relevant page.

Comment: There is no -d formula option for me in doxygen 1.9.5 ("error: option "-d" has unknown debug specifier: "formula".) I can not USE_MATHJAX=YES , because I have commands with optional arguments in my formula file.

Comment: Indeed 1.9.5 has no `-d formula`, this has bee added for the 1.9.8 version, so you will have to look through the formula log files that are on the html directory and deduce from that which formula is the problem, will probably show near the end of the file. Otherwise some counting in the formula tex file on the html directore or the alternative with MathJax or update dixygen.

Comment: I was able to figure out the problem (see update). Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Interestingly, looks like all is defined in the same way, a bit confusing is that you now speak about formula 99 / 100 and before it was 93, probably this is due to the multi threading so for consistent output (during the debug that is now performed)  set `NUM_PROC_THREADS=1` (at least when this is not already the case). Any possibility to create a small problem we can run (as it looks like you know which formula is causing the problem?

Comment: No I removed/added some equations for debugging purposes. There is no multithreading. The issue is the usage of mathbb with small letters. I changed to upper case letters (like for A) and the issue is gone now.

Comment: Interesting, might have to do something with the used / available fonts as I saw https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38769/mathbbz-yields-undefined-control-sequence-error(though this is with uppercase characters and your problem looks like lower case character problem). No idea without a small example so we can try to reproduce is.

Comment: @albert I added an minimal example demonstrating the problem. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: I could reproduce the problem and it looks like it falls in the same category as shown in the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/how-do-you-get-mathbb1-to-work-characteristic-function-of-a-set I tried the bbm alternative and this worked but probably the alternative given in the answer regarding newtxmath might be better (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532611/44119) or the answer given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583600/44119 or some of the other answers with that issue.